# Collison detection trouble. (c++ SDL2)

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sdl2, logic

I have a small trouble with my collsion detection system, ill show it on images.
im checking the detection by using that logic with example when moving to the right:

```
obj.x+obj.w+obj.mov > block.x
obj.x+obj.w+obj.mov < block.x+block.w
and
(
    obj.y <= block.y
    obj.y+obj.h >= block.y
    or
    obj.y <= block.y+block.h
    obj.y+obj.h >= block.y+block.h
)
```

[image: detection1]

when object size and block size are equal, the problem appears

[image: detection2]

the 3 blocks are detected

1 = is the trouble maker

2 = isnt making much problem, since its on same axis

3 =  is working

the 1 block is detected since its within Y + H area of the block (

it happens when the object is sticked with 0 pixel distance.

im using motion based on min(mov,dist) [dist is Y distance between object and block] function and when it tries to move to the right, it gets moved like that

[image: detection 3]

because min(mov,dist) will become negative when getting distance to object 1 instead of 3, making it buggy

im asking if its possible to prevent block 1 (block 2 optionaly) when that situation happens. (or atleast change the logic)

Comment: i have fixed the negative jump, but the logic still needs to be fixed, cause it gets stuck on edges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have solved it, logic should look like this

```
     obj.x+obj.w+obj.mov > block.x
     obj.x+obj.w+obj.mov < block.x+block.w
    and
    (
        obj.y <= block.y
        obj.y+obj.h >= block.y
        or
        obj.y <= block.y+block.h
        obj.y+obj.h >= block.y+block.h
    )
    and
     obj.y != block.y+block.h
    and
     obj.y+obj.h != block.y
```

Answer (score 3):

At a glance, your code is doing what it's supposed to, which is detecting collisions (distance between 2 edges <= 0).

It sounds like you want to detect *intersections* instead, which is two AABB's overlapping. In which case, change:

```
and
(
    obj.y <= block.y
    obj.y+obj.h >= block.y
    or
    obj.y <= block.y+block.h
    obj.y+obj.h >= block.y+block.h
)
```

To:

```
and
(
    obj.y < block.y
    obj.y+obj.h > block.y
    or
    obj.y < block.y+block.h
    obj.y+obj.h > block.y+block.h
)
```

Comment: i tried that before, it works, but when it goes Y axis, it will simply go throught the blocks http://imgur.com/a/kya7d, (Y axis uses same logic as X axis).

Comment: Read this: it should help you out: https://studiofreya.com/3d-math-and-physics/simple-aabb-vs-aabb-collision-detection/